# Accessing Symbols of dynamic module from static module in linux

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I have a requirement such that i want to call a function which is defined in my loadbale kernel module (.ko ) from a static kernel module.

When i tried building, my static module could not find symbol during likning stage.
So I would like to know whether this scenario is possible.

Thanks for your inputs

Comment: I have tried with Export symbol and it doesnt work out. As per my understanding Export symbol is used access the symbols of one loadable module by another loadable module.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for you is to use the Device Driver Framwork with your own specific BUS object where your two
modules will register to.